# Convertir consulta mysql a query builder de laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta funcionando bien en mysql

```
DELETE FROM solicitudes 
WHERE fecha_solicitud + (SELECT valor FROM parametros WHERE id=3) < CURRENT_DATE() 
AND id not in (select solicitude_id from seguimientos where estado_ejemplare_id!=2);
```

Quisiera convertirla a query builder de laravel y he hecho lo siguiente

```
DB::table('solicitudes')
        ->where(DB::raw('fecha_solicitud + (select valor from parametros where id=3)'), '>', DB::raw('current_date()'))
        ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('seguimientos')->select('solicitude_id')->where('estado_ejemplare_id', '<>', 2)->get())
        ->delete();
```

Pero no me funciona ni me marca ningun error, que podria ser, ya he revisado el nombre de las tablas y los campos y si estan bien, debe ser la estructura.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tienes invertido el _menor que_ en `) < CURRENT_DATE()`. En el query builder tienes `'>', DB:raw('current_date()')`

Comment: Remplaza el ````->delete()```` por ````->get()```` y comprueba si realmente te trae los registros que deseas eliminar. En la sub-consulta de seguimientos esta debería retornar un array de objeto con una sola propiedad, mientras lo que espera el where in es un array de valores, prueba agregar ````->pluck('solicitude_id')````

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, con las dos observaciones que me hicieron pude solucionar el problema, opte por cambiar el signo y el método a pluck.

Comment: Alguno de los dos, ponga la respuesta como respuesta abajo en la sección Tu Respuesta :) Con eso, kevin podrá marcarla como aceptada